# detailed representation of perf record

Tags: subprocess, report, record, perf

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOsKB.png)
I have a question about the representation of perf record; perf report for Linux.

I would like a detailed illustration of the function's workload.
My output is very confusing. Nice would be a table with a representation, where the subprocesses are indented in the table and showing, how long a function stays there.
Thereby I want to map the behavior of the function in subprocesses, i.e. I want to see how long a function lasts and how long it stays in subcategories.

Can anyone help me with this? How is that possible?

Thank you and best regards :)

P.s.: I think a representation like in the attached picture would be completely sufficient.
But it never shows me this way.

Comment: Related: [How to use linux perf tool for code comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31882904)

Comment: You should try https://www.speedscope.app/ to visualize perf profiles with this instruction: https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope/wiki/Importing-from-perf-(linux). speedscope has some support of processes too and also has a timeline.